# ODE, Lyapunov function: every forward orbit is defined and bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with smooth $f(x)$. By $x_t$, denote some orbit. Assume there exists a Lyapunov function at infinity for $\dot{x}=f(x)$, i.e. a function $V\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with the following two properties:

- $V(x)\to+\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert\to +\infty$
- $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}f(x)\le 0$ for all $\lVert x\rVert\ge K$ for some $K>0$

> > **Theorem.** If the system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with smooth $f(x)$ has a Lyapunov function at infinity, then every forward orbit is defined and bounded for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$.

In the reading, we had a very short proof:

If $\varphi(t)$ is not bounded $\implies \forall R>0~\exists t: \varphi(t) >R, \dot{\varphi}(t)>0.$
$$
R=\max_{\lVert x\rVert\le K}V(x),
$$
then
$$
t:~~V(x_t)>R,~~~~~\frac{d}{dt}V(x_t)>0
$$
which is a contradiction.

---

I have some problems to understand this proof. First of all this seems to be a proof by contradiction. And the assumption seems to be that there is some forward orbit that is **not** defined and bounded for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$.
Denote this orbit by $x_t$.

I guess that $x_t$ is not defined for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$ only can mean that it tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ for some $s\in [0,+\infty)$. Hence, it is not bounded. But why should this imply that $\forall R>0\exists t: x_t>R$ and $\dot{x}_t>0$>?

Moreover, if, for some $t$, $V(x_t)>R$ for $R=\max_{\lVert x\rVert\le K}V(x)$, why does this imply that $\frac{d}{dt}V(x_t)>0$?

Comment: About $\frac{d}{dt} V(x_t)$: just use chain rule of differentiation.